# Click button to highlight a Map Marker (Gmaps) - how?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

On this [page](http://codepupil.com/gmap-test/) I need the "Get Directions," button to highlight one of three points/map markers already on the map.  So far, I have the following wrapped around the button/img....

```html
<a href="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + 37.7029 + "," + -121.9335 + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false"><img src="images/get-directions.jpg" alt="get directions"></a><br>
```

Though that code is not working. Any idea, where I went wrong with that code or know a better way?

Comment: You are using a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map on [the linked page](http://codepupil.com/gmap-test/), why don't you just use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)?  And why don't you write code using that to "highlight a marker" as you ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using static map url but you have [embed map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode)?

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions
  ?key=API_KEY
  &origin=
  &destination=
```

Comment: Thank you, but Im not sure what you mean.  Though when I click the, "Get Directions," button I am taken to a new page with the an error that says, "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Missing the 'size' parameter."

Comment: From looking at your URL, its using Static map API, but your actual map looks like its using Embed API